# Are there anywhere I can find 7.5 versions of CentOS for download?

Tags: centos

I am going to upgrade a e107 server locally in VMware before doing it for the real server. This will enable me to verify that all will work well when I upgrade. As I will not be able to affect the environment of the server, I will have to download CentOS 7.5.1804 somewhere. I am however not able to find any mirrors where this is available,

http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7.5.1804/isos/x86_64/

Where to find old downloads of CentOS?

Comment: Can you get an image of the server instead?

Comment: If you really need CentOS 7.5 in order to test an upgrade you can find the iso for any previous release here http://vault.centos.org/

Comment: @admstg This link worked well.

Comment: @StephenKitt I think this might be hard (from a security point of view), but I can try as this might be the easiest way to deal with the problem. The thought is good at least. Also, I suspect this is a stationary server and not a virtual. It does not make things so much harder, but it is less likely there will be a ready image lying around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find what you want at http://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/centos/7.5.1804/isos/x86_64/